# Query database at program.cs

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an intranet application, authorization would be claim-based. So I would need to set up the authorization policy at program.cs. The authorization is based on Azure AD's user groups. It's a simple application, so user groups would change probably only once every couple years. My idea is that:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // GetGroupsObjectIdFromDatabase() would return AzureAD's object ID, 
    // which is pre-populated in the db before the application runs
    options.AddPolicy(
      "ITOnly", 
      policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups", GetGroupsObjectIdFromDatabase()));
});
```

So, how do I set up in program.cs so that I would be able to make a db call here?

Alternatively, if that is not possible, how do people set up the authorization policy here?

Comment: Why not use appsettings. it is easy to use in program.cs.

Comment: appsettings require that I know everything at compile time.

Comment: Do you want to read the different database depending on policy name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using efcore to read database is a general way. but it need to be DI initialized in program.cs . So you cannot use efocre here. SQlconnection is a way to read databse without efcore.
For example, i have a sql server database like
[image]

We need a `User.cs` like

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

You can write code like below in `program.cs` ,you need install nuget package `system.data.sqlclient`

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();

List<User> _users = new();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.2.68;Database=Users;User Id=sa;Password=Q!q11111;"))
{
    connection.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM UserList";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                _users.Add(new User { Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Username = reader.GetString(1), Password = reader.GetString(2) });
            }
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Then you will get the whole users table into `_users`.To use a value such as username 'Tom`. You can use like below.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy(
      "ITOnly",
      policy => policy.RequireClaim("groups", _users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).Username));
});
```